# Special right for ON DELETE CASCADE using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to allow Supper Admin right for ON DELETE CASCADE to my SQL Table using MVC while it is disabled for other users?

Note: I already have my user role correctly setup and want that when a special user logs in, he should be able to cascade delete some item from the database but not allowed for other users.

Thanks in advance.